# My code isn't running past the 'while loop'

Tags: python, while-loop

```
password = input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:')
while password == 'no':
    paid = int(input('How much money have you paid:'))
    name = input('What is the camper\'s name:')
    
    if paid == '120':
        print(name, 'Your sport is football')
    
    if paid == '200':
        print(name, 'Your sport is Basketball')
        password = str(input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:'))
    
    if paid == '225':
        print(name, 'Your sport is Netball')
        password = str(input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:'))
    
    if paid == '275':
        print(name, 'Your sport is Hockey')
        password = str(input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:'))
    
    if paid == '300':
        print(name, 'Your sport is swimming')
        password = str(input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:'))
```

**Output**

```
 runfile('C:/Users/camro_803vhwj/Desktop/ITSBA inpython.py', wdir='C:/Users/camro_803vhwj/Desktop')

Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:yes
```

The output above is the only thing that is coming out when I want all 3 of the prompts.
How do I get the prompts to get; name, paid and password to happen one after the next?

Comment: ```password.lower() != 'no'``` - is needed. You said to do if ```password``` is equal to ```no```. Of course, ```yes``` is never equal to ```no```. Hence, it doesn't run

Comment: You made `paid` an `int`, but you're comparing it with strings. Those comparisons will always evaluate as `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following code will do the job.

```
password = input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:')
while password == 'yes':
    paid = int(input('How much money have you paid:'))
    name = input('What is the camper\'s name:')

    if paid == 120:
        print(name, 'Your sport is football')
    elif paid == 200:
        print(name, 'Your sport is Basketball')
    elif paid == 225:
        print(name, 'Your sport is Netball')
    elif paid == 275:
        print(name, 'Your sport is Hockey')
    elif paid == 300:
        print(name, 'Your sport is swimming')
    else: 
        print (name, "Unknown")        
    password = str(input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:'))

print ('End of Program.')
```

I think the 'else' was necessary but remove it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line while password == 'no': to while password != 'no':
If the user gives an input of  string 'no', it then exits the loop

Answer (score 0):

`password.lower() != 'no'` - is needed. You said to go through the loop if password is equal to no. Of course, yes is never equal to no. Hence, it doesn't run.

Therefore You need to replace your statement to `password.lower() != 'no'`

Also,when you execute the while loop, it will always evaluate to FALSE. Therefore, change all the numbers to integers by removing the single inverted commas

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you wantedthe program to do, but maybe this one:

```
pw=input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:')
while pw=='no':
    paid=int(input('How much money have you paid:'))
    name=input('What is the camper\'s name:')
    if paid==120:
        print(name, 'Your sport is football')
    else:
        if paid==200:
            print(name, 'Your sport is Basketball')
        elif paid==225:
            print(name, 'Your sport is Netball')
        elif paid==275:
            print(name, 'Your sport is Hockey')
        elif paid==300:
            print(name, 'Your sport is swimming')
        pw=input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:')
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed the input to `int`, but you kept the values you're checking against `str`. You need to make them both `int` or both `str`. Of those two options, the latter is better, as you don't have to do input validation to avoid throwing an error if the input isn't a valid `int`. It's also a good idea to have guards against infinite loops. Finally, your code can be made much simpler by using a dictionary.

```
max_iterations = 100
sport_lookup = {'120':'football',
    '200':'Basketball',
    '225':'Netball',
    '275':'Hockey',
    '300':'swimming'
    }
for iteration in range(max_iterations):
    password = input('Do you wish to add a camper, answer with yes or no:')
    if password != 'yes':
        break
    paid = input('How much money have you paid:')
    name = input('What is the camper\'s name:')
    print(name, 'Your sport is '+sport_lookup[paid])
```